# Why are my rails test all passing on my computer, but some aren't passing in my Github action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-actions

I have been trying to create a Github Action where it runs my rails test as I push to my main branch. I run `rails test` on my terminal, and all of the tests passed, but when I try to run the tests in my main.yml file in my workflow on github, it fails only 2 tests, both relating to deleting an object with a relationship with another object (with a foreign key).

When I run my rails test through my terminal, this is my output

```
Running 74 tests in parallel using 2 processes
DEBUGGER: Attaching after process 42736 fork to child process 42753
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#42754]: Attaching after process 42736 fork to child process 42754
Started with run options --seed 10960

  74/74: [=================================] 100% Time: 00:00:04, Time: 00:00:04

Finished in 5.09323s
74 tests, 135 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

When I push to my main branch on Github, this is my output for the tests

```
Running 74 tests in parallel using 2 processes
DEBUGGER: Attaching after process 3336 fork to child process 3357
DEBUGGER[bin/rails#3359]: Attaching after process 3336 fork to child process 3359
Started with run options --seed 27863


Progress: |=========ERROR ReviewsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_review (3.88s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         DRb::DRbRemoteError: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "reviews" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_7314ea0830" on table "restaurants"
        DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "restaurants".
         (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
            app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:52:in `destroy'
            test/controllers/reviews_controller_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ReviewsControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/reviews_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:ReviewsControllerTest>'

=========ERROR HalalItemsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_halal_item (4.09s)
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         DRb::DRbRemoteError: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "halal_items" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_0fa9986d41" on table "restaurants"
        DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "restaurants".
         (ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey)
            app/controllers/halal_items_controller.rb:52:in `destroy'
            test/controllers/halal_items_controller_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:HalalItemsControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/halal_items_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:HalalItemsControllerTest>'

==================================================|

Finished in 5.04433s
74 tests, 131 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is what my main.yml looks like

```
name: Ruby

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: **redacted**
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: **redacted**
          POSTGRES_USER: **redacted**
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
          gem install bundler
      - name: Install gems
        run: |
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - name: Setup database
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: **redacted**
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
        run: bundle exec rails db:prepare
      - name: Run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: **redacted**
          RAILS_ENV: test
          DISABLE_SPRING: 1
        run: bundle exec rails test
```

Here are the models for the reviews, halal items, and restaurants (some of the relations are not relevant for this question)

```
app/models/review.rb
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :restaurant
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :halal_item
end
```

```
app/models/halal_items.rb
class HalalItem < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :restaurant
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :nullify
end
```

```
app/models/restaurants.rb
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :halal_items, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Here are the tests that are failing in my Github action, but not locally (with the associated controller)

```
/test/controllers/halal_items_controller_test.rb
test "should destroy halal_item" do
    assert_difference("HalalItem.count", -1) do
      delete halal_item_url(@halal_item)
    end

    assert_redirected_to halal_items_url
end
/app/controllers/halal_items_controller.rb
  def destroy
    @halal_item.destroy # this was line that the test was failing on

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to halal_items_url, notice: "Halal item was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

```
/test/controllers/reviews_controller_test.rb
  test "should destroy review" do
    assert_difference("Review.count", -1) do
      delete review_url(@review)
    end

    assert_redirected_to reviews_url
  end
/app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
  def destroy
    @review.destroy # this was line that the test was failing on

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: "Review was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Highly likely `main.yml` per se is irrelevant to the problem. Could you show you models definitions (just the part where relations are defined) and failing tests code instead, please?..

Comment: The PostgreSQL database complains about not-meet foreign key constraints. I guess you run locally a database that does not support foreign key constraints, SQLite for example.

Comment: @spickermann I am using PostgreSQL locally and remotely, so I am not sure if this would be the reason for my issue.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I have added the model definitions and the failing tests code as well.

Comment: Your test environment database seems to be a bit inconsistent with your model definitions. Your error says "update or delete on table 'reviews' violates foreign key constraint... on table 'restaurants'... Key ... is still referenced from table 'restaurants'". But according to your model definitions, _a restaurant has many reviews and items, not vice versa_. So these constraints your db complains about don't make any sense - FK constraints should sit on the "opposite side" of the relation and "seal" `restaurant_id` (or other) FK in `reviews` and `halal_items`.

Comment: Any time my tests pass locally but don't pass in CI it means that my local database and the CI database aren't the same. You need to run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate db:seed` and then retry your test suite to confirm it still works locally.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov after a couple of weeks of trying to sort out the FK issue, it was finally figured out that this was the issue causing the tests to fail in github actions, but not locally. Thanks a lot!